Security threats when using bar() vs bar(void)
For HW in a security class, I want to demonstrate an attack that relies on the difference between bar() (tells the compiler that the number and type of arguments is unknown) and bar(void) (tells the compiler that the function doesn't take arguments).
I've seen this thread that details their difference, but haven't been able to create a successful attack based off of it.
My code is:
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(){
    int a = 4;
    printf("%d", a);
}


int main() {
    bar("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");

    return 0;
}

I'm expecting for the passed string to overrun the variable 'a', but it doesn't happen.
Starngely enough, when examining the stack with gdb (using 'info frame'), it doesn't say that the string has been even passed.

Most implementations simply ignore extra arguments, for historic reasons.

There is no question in your post. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions.

I'm not sure how a C program that "attacks" another function running in the same memory-space is doing anything of value, given that (as a C program) you have full access to the same memory as whatever function you call (and OS/system-lib functions are just wrappers over syscalls which are immune to this kind of "threat").

Huh, I always thought that the declaration on a definition is always a prototype, but apparently not.

Maybe some old school K&R C had these types of issues... but it's going to be real hard to find a compiler these days that doesn't put guardrails on those ancient issues.  You'll have better luck exploiting a function with buffer overrun issue or a variable argument function in which an expected variable parameter is missing.  e.g. printf("%s%s", p);

At least as of C89, a function definition with an empty argument list is equivalent to an argument list of void; otherwise the number and types of arguments is unspecified (6.7.6.3/14).


Starngely enough, when examining the stack with gdb (using 'info
frame'), it doesn't say that the string has been even passed.

The strings are not passed in the C language by value only by pointer. So you pass the reference to the string literal "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" String literal will be stored where implementation stores constant data (not on the stack)
If you want to pass by value large array you need to use structures which are passed by value.
bar((struct {char a[30];}){"hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"});

It will be placed on the stack (with optimizations disabled)
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        movabs  rax, 7523377975159973992
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdx
        movabs  rax, 7523377975159973992
        mov     edx, 26728
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-18], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-10], rdx
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     rcx, rsp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx+8], rdx
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-18]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-10]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx+14], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx+22], rdx
        mov     eax, 0
        call    bar
        add     rsp, 32
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret

But the called function will create its own stack frame  - separate from the main function one
bar:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        nop
        leave
        ret

So nothing dangerous will happen as both stack frames do not overlap.

Let's thing about this logically. If you have a foo() function that accepts any numbers of parameters, there are two cases:

The function's implementation was being made while being aware of this fact and knowingly appealing to the parameters to be received
The function's implementation was being made while being unaware of this fact and therefore not referring to the possibly received parameters

So, if you write code that maliciously calls the function, then based on your call the function would still be defined in a parameterized manner, but the parameters passed would either be expected and welcomed by the function, or unexpected and ignored.
So there is no real danger inside the function.
There is a mild "danger" outside the function, as this way, if you compile two different codes with foo() being defined in both and then reverse-engineer them and put them together, you may end up with conflicting definitions. But if that happens, such an issue can be fixed and it's not worth the trouble for the hackers to induce a bug that can easily be fixed. No data theft, not even data damage is involved.
Nevertheless, the real danger of such a function as foo() is that it's obsolescence and some compilers might refuse to allow it from some point onwards.
EDIT
@Caulder has made a useful remark in the comment section, stating:

I think the real danger is a variadic function, expecting arguments, that aren't given, thus trashing other memory.


I think the real danger is a variadic function, expecting arguments, that aren't given, thus trashing other memory.

It is common in modern architectures that arguments are passed simply by a calling routine putting the argument values in specific designated places (in processor registers or in the hardware stack). Then a called routine with a parameter corresponding to some argument will use the argument by getting its value from the designated place.
If the called routine does not have such a parameter, it will not get the value from the designated place. Then nothing else will happen in relation to the argument. The calling routine may have put a value in the designated place, but the called routine will not use it. Nothing will be overrun. The argument is simply ignored and has no effect.
No attack can be effected in this situation.
There are other methods of passing arguments which may require more interaction and cooperation between calling routines and called routines, but, most likely, you are not using a computing platform with such methods in your security class.

Even if the parameter will be passed by value - nothing will happen as main and bar will have separate stack frames - so nothing will overlap (as shown in my answer)

The arguments are passed somewhere (register/stack/heap) depending on the ABI, but if the callee for examples never pops the stack, then the arguments won't be accessed. The variable a is allocated on function entry, so after the arguments got written in the caller, before the call, thus it can't be overwritten.
I'm no expert, but maybe you are able to overwrite the return address that is used by the callee via your approach.
But I wouldn't consider that a security issue, because as the caller, you are responsible for writing the return address, so you can write something there anyways.

No you will not overwrite anything.

@0___________ But isn't the return address written before the arguments, so that the callee has to know the arguments in order to access the return address correctly?

@0___________
Wouldn't it then be possible to let the caller specify another (potentially incorrect) return address via the OP's approach?

no - it is not possible

@0___________ Sorry, but why not?
